# Android Studio using Method Tracer to determine cold start launch-time performance

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to determine the cold launch performance of my application. I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html) guide.

I want to use the Method Tracer tool in Android Studio, but according to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-cpu.html#running) guide it seems like there is no way to attach to the process and automatically begin profiling.

Is there really no easy way to use the CPU Method Tracing for cold start performance?

Comment: Yeah, there is a wonky work around. So you can also add in a service into your manifest. Have it launch at boot time. The process will then be launched. Now you can attach to the method tracer and launch your activity.